# Android custom ListView item setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView item. setOnClickListener is not working. I've been searching for the solution for hours, but couldn't find anything. I think the problem is not 'set focusable false' things, because I've already done it. Please, help me.

**payments_list_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="35.3dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/payment_item_name2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|start"
        android:src="@drawable/payments_internet"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:capitalize="words" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#8c8c8c"
    android:id="@+id/payment_item_name"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:capitalize="words" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15.3dp"
        android:layout_height="20.1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_red"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:textAllCaps = "true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Activity onCreate:

```
ListView paymentsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paymentsList);                    
paymentsList.setAdapter(testAdapter);
paymentsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Log.w("Clicked23", "CLicked23");
     }
});
```

`

My Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View payments_list_item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payments_list_item, parent, false);
    String payment = getItem(position);
    TextView payment_item_name = (TextView) payments_list_item.findViewById(R.id.payment_item_name);
    payment_item_name.setText(payment.toUpperCase());
    return payments_list_item;
}
```

**//EDIT**
**Finally solved my problem**
Thanks to @mustafasevgi`s answer:

I added

**android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"** to my custom ListView item layout.

Comment: Please attach the code that fails.

Comment: I just added @WilliamRosenbloom.

Comment: `Log.w` not printing ??

Comment: Not just Log.w. I've tried starting new Activity, Toast etc. All not working.

Comment: for good approach you can check `payments_list_item` is null or not

Comment: @user3163150 can you post your total code

Comment: Items are appearing, all is working as it has to be. The problem is with setOnItemClickListener.

Comment: did you try with `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Comment: If you consider custom listview item view, yes I've done it. I'll just add my xml code as well.

Comment: Please post your xml payments_list_item also

Comment: Please post layout xml Listview and Item Listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add this code?

> android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

**payment_list_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="35.3dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/payment_item_name2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|start"
            android:src="@drawable/payments_internet"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:capitalize="words" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#8c8c8c"
        android:id="@+id/payment_item_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:capitalize="words" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15.3dp"
            android:layout_height="20.1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_red"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:textAllCaps = "true"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you very much! Gardaş =) @mustafasevgi

Answer (score 0):

check the following code:

```
public class CustomListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView paymentsList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list);//your layout view
paymentsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paymentsList);
paymentsList.setAdapter(testAdapter);
paymentsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
  //your logic
 Toast.makeText(this, "Listview Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   paymentsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
           Log.w("Clicked23", "CLicked23");
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your xml

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

how about modifying your `payments_list_item` to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/payment_item_name2"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="35.3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/payments_internet"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/payment_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="#8c8c8c"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="15.3dp"
        android:layout_height="20.1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_red"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

you have written very complex layout..